# Checking file permissions in a QThread, with Retry/Cancel dialog box (in the GUI thread)

Tags: python, pyside2

I have a process running in a QThread which generates some data I want to save to a file. Before doing this I need to check that I have the proper permissions for writing to the file (this is on Windows), and I would really like to use a `QtWidgets.QMessageBox` with a "Retry" and a "Cancel" option. This is easily done via for example (the typical issue in my case is that the user has the xlsx file open in Excel)

```
reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(
    self, "PermissionError",
    "Could not open file \"%s\". Try closing the file if it is open." % filename,
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.StandardButton.Retry,
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.StandardButton.Cancel
)
```

but this only works in the main (GUI) thread, not in the separate QThread. What is a good way to do this from the QThread?

I have made some tests with a signal from the QThread sent to a slot in the GUI thread which opens the dialog. But I find it hard to communicate back to the QThread the result of the permission check, and the logic quickly becomes messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the experience that I have the approach to *subclassify QThread* is not good for these cases.

A simple solution is to use the *worker(QThread)-thread* approach since the worker can have several tasks such as doing the heavy calculation and saving the file. So the GUI could launch the first task, then the worker who lives in another thread make the request for confirmation by signals to the GUI, then the GUI according to the result you have can call the other task.

An example of the above is the following:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    requestSignal = QtCore.Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(parent)
        self.data = None

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def process(self):
        print("start process")
        # emulate heavy task
        QtCore.QThread.sleep(5)
        self.data = "Foo"
        print("end process")
        self.requestSignal.emit("filename.xlsx")

    @QtCore.Slot(bool)
    def save_data(self, result):
        print(result)
        print(self.data)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    sendResult = QtCore.Signal(bool)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.m_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            "Press me", clicked=self.start_process
        )
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_button)

        self.m_thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        self.m_thread.start()

        self.m_worker = Worker()
        self.m_worker.moveToThread(self.m_thread)
        self.m_worker.requestSignal.connect(self.on_request)
        self.sendResult.connect(self.m_worker.save_data)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def start_process(self):
        # launch process
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.m_worker.process)
        self.m_button.setDisabled(True)

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def on_request(self, filename):
        reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(
            self,
            "PermissionError",
            'Could not open file "%s". Try closing the file if it is open.'
            % filename,
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Retry,
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel,
        )
        result = reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Retry
        print(result)
        self.sendResult.emit(result)
        self.m_button.setDisabled(False)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        super(Widget, self).closeEvent(event)
        self.m_thread.quit()
        self.m_thread.wait()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This is similar to the solution I was leaning towards, but couldn't get the logic sorted out. You have done a good job at that, so I'll try it out!

Comment: "to subclassify QThread is not good for these cases" - what approach would you suggest instead?

Comment: @FilipS. As I point out in my answer: use a worker (QObject) that lives in another thread

Comment: Oh, I see the distinction now. Thanks!